# With Gmaps4rails, how can I display a list of locations that are currently visible in the map view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I am using gmaps4rails. I am trying to achieve the following: The map is showing locations with markers and the user can zoom/move his window of sight as he wishes. What I want is that as he does so, a list next to the map should dynamically update with all the locations that are currently visible. 
I tried using the callback mechanism and getBounds to filter a data structure of what is visible, but without success.
How can I go about it?

Thanks a lot!
Julian

In my controller:  class LocationsController < ApplicationController

```
  def index
    if (params[:sw_y] && params[:sw_x] && params[:ne_y] && params[:ne_x])
        bounds = [ [params[:sw_x].to_f, params[:sw_y].to_f], 
                 [params[:ne_x].to_f, params[:ne_y].to_f] ]
        @locations_within_bounds = Location.within_bounds(bounds)
    else
        @locations_within_bounds = Location.all
    end   
  @locations = Location.all
  @json = Location.all.to_gmaps4rails
```

And in my view:

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json, "options" => {"list_container" => "markers_list", "do_clustering" => true } }   ) %>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Longitude</th>
    <th>Latitude</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @locations_within_bounds.each do |location| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= location.name %></td>
    <td><%= location.address %></td>
    <td><%= location.longitude %></td>
    <td><%= location.latitude %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: the idea is good, I guess the implementation fails

Comment: so this cant be done with gmaps4rails? I do see such behavior elsewhere on the web, hence I am wondering how to do it.

Comment: It can be done with gmaps4rails. Your implementation fails somewhere. Any code?

Comment: added my code fragments above in the question